# Counting and grouping with further checks

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Currently I'm getting results doing the following:

```
SELECT Progress, COUNT(*) AS counter
FROM finished
GROUP BY Progress
```

Then displaying the result as follows:

```
if($row['Progress'] == '0') {
    echo $row['counter'];
}
if($row['Progress'] == '1') {
    if (($row['date_sent'] !== '0000-00-00 00:00:00') && ($row['notes'] !== '0')) {
        echo $row['counter'];
    } else if ($row['date_sent'] !== '0000-00-00 00:00:00') {
        echo $row['counter'];
    }
}
```

However I would like to group these numbers if possible, so if something has a progress value of 1, date sent = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" and notes = 1, then it counts those rows and it also counts rows that have 0 notes.

Is this possible?

What I need is to count

```
SELECT * FROM finished WHERE Progress=1 date_sent = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND notes = 0
```

then to count

```
SELECT * FROM finished WHERE Progress=1 date_sent = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND notes != 0
```

as well as also counting Progress=0, Progress=2 and Progress=3, although 2/3 are not required as of this moment.

EDIT to show something I'm trying:

```
SELECT Progress, 
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM finished WHERE date_sent is NULL AND notes = 0) as firstcount,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM finished WHERE date_sent is NULL) as secondcount
FROM finished
GROUP BY Progress
```

Also, if there are no notes, but progress is 1, it is not required to be counted.

Comment: well isn't that what "Count(*) as counter" does?

Comment: So you are asking us how to query the database and get those results rigt

Comment: @Cr1xus `Count(*) as counter` is counting them grouped together, not taking in to account the other columns. So currently I'm getting the result of 13 for both counters, as it's just showing the counter for Progress = 1.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm just unsure of how to count them with an extra filter.

Comment: An extra filter in the SQL, right?

Comment: you want to get one counter from the database where the column date_sent is 0000-00-00 AND notes is 1 ?
or do you want to count it in PHP?

Comment: @Purefan I hadn't considered counting in PHP as I assumed if I could count the rows as it as it was making the query it would be a better way of doing things.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ideally yes. Am just going to edit the original with something I'm trying, it's giving me results, but not right ones!

Comment: `sent is NULL) as secondcount` ==> `sent is NULL AND notes != 0) as secondcount` otherwise you're overlapping results

Comment: Your if statements are confusing, the second if is basically `if($row['Progress'] == '1' && $row['date_sent'] !== '0000-00-00 00:00:00') echo $row['counter'];`

Comment: Assuming that 'Progress' can be only 0 or 1 your php code will be equivalent to this `if($row['date_sent'] !== '0000-00-00 00:00:00') echo $row['counter];`

Comment: @Cr1xus Progress can be anywhere from 0 to 5, however I only want to get the ones that are in progress 0/1. If they are in stage 1 and have a note they are in a sub-stage.

Comment: @BN83 Ok. So are you sure, looking at your edit, that date_sent is actually NULL? Better said is NULL =  '0000-00-00 00:00:00'? try WHERE date_sent='0000-00-00 00:00:00' .

Comment: I get the same results with NULL or all the zeros. I don't think the results are grouped properly. What I need is to count `SELECT * FROM finished WHERE Progress=1 date_sent = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND notes = 0` then to count `SELECT * FROM finished WHERE Progress=1 date_sent = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND notes != 0` as well as also counting Progress=0, Progress=2 and Progress=3, although 2/3 are not required as of this moment.